# Can't get rid of same records

Tags: perl

I have a input file that existing so many redundant records , I try to write a program to remove the part of redundance , But it seems still remain some redundance , but I can't find out what's wrong with it

ARGV[0] is the input file with redundance

ARGV[1] is the output file without redundance of the input file

```
open(Input,"<./$ARGV[0]");
open(Output,">./$ARGV[1]");

while( eof(Input) !=1)
{
    push(@Records,readline(*Input));
}
close Input;

# Solution 2
for($i=0;$i<$#Records;$i++)
{
    for($j=$i+1;$j<$#Records;$j++)
    {
        if($Records[$i] eq $Records[$j])
        {
            $Records[$j] = undef;
        }
    }
}

@Records = grep defined,@Records;

=begin
# Solution 1 have some problems
for($i=0;$i<$#Records;$i++)
{
    for($j=$i+1;$j<$#Records;$j++)
    {
        if($Records[$i] eq $Records[$j])
        {
            splice @Records,$j,1;
            $j = $j-1;  
        }
    }
}
=end
=cut

foreach $Each(@Records)
{
    print Output $Each;
}
close Output;
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your “solution 1” is the closest. Setting an array element to `undef` doesn't remove it, and will cause a warning message if you have warnings enabled as you should.

This solution checks each record at index `$j` and either removes it using `splice` if it is a duplicate (which will shuffle the remaining records down so that the next record to be compared will be at *the same index*) or leaves it in place and skips over it by incrementing `$j`.

It is best practice to use lexical file handles (like `$infh`) rather than bare word file handles (like `Input`). You should also use the three-parameter form of `open`, and *always* check whether it has succeeded. Here I have used `autodie` to avoid checking every `open` explicitly. It will throw an exception if any `open` call fails.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my ($infile, $outfile) = @ARGV;

my @records = do {
    open my $infh, '<', $infile;
    <$infh>;
};

for my $i (0..$#records-1) {
    my $j = $i + 1;
    while ($j < @records) {
        if ($records[$j] eq $records[$i]) {
            splice @records, $j, 1;
        }
        else {
            ++$j;
        }
    }
}

open my $outfh, '>', $outfile;
print $outfh $_ for @records;
close $outfh;
```

An alternative solution using a hash looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my ($infile, $outfile) = @ARGV;

open my $infh,  '<', $infile;
open my $outfh, '>', $outfile;

my %seen;

while (<$infh>) {
  print $outfh $_ unless $seen{$_}++;
}
```

Comment: don't forget to close the file handles

Comment: Lexical filehandles are closed automatically when they go out of scope, so it's generally not necessary to explicitly close them.

Answer (score 2):

This is a more perl-modern solution:

```
open(my $fh_input, '<', $ARGV[0]) or die $!;
open(my $fh_output, '>', $ARGV[1]) or die $!;
my %records = ();

while( my $line = <$fh_input> )
{
   $records{$line} = 1;
}

foreach my $record(keys %records)
{
    print $fh_output $record;
}

close $fh_input;
close $fh_output;
```

As you can see, I used a hash to avoid duplications

Comment: This will randomise the order of the input records, which is unlikely to be what is wanted.

Comment: use Tie::IxHash; if the order is important

Comment: That is clumsy and unnecessary. Just print each line as it is read from the input file if it hasn't been seen before. See the update to my solution.

Comment: If the target is printing, I agree. If not and further processing is necessary, this way may helps

Comment: OK forget printing. Just *process* each line as it is read from the input file if it hasn't been seen before. Can you describe a situation where your approach will work better?

Comment: I said it, when you need process with state than depends on past, present and future reads

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `uniq()`.

```
my @records;
while( eof(Input) !=1)
{
    push(@records,readline(*Input));
}
close Input;

@records = uniq(@records); ## Unique elements in @records
```

Please have a look at its documentation [here](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aUniq).

Comment: I found that I can't use uniq even I use use 

"use List::MoreUtils qw/uniq/; " ....

Comment: I use "@records = uniq(@records);" but system shows "Can't locate List/MoreUtils.pm in @INC ......" I think it's because I import the wrong module?

Comment: @KrishnachandraSharma: I don't understand what advice you are trying to give. Both `List::Uniq` and `List::MoreUtils` export a `uniq` function, but neither are core modules and must be installed before they can be used. Also, either one will need a `use` statement in the program, so your advice to *"simply add @records = uniq(@records)"* will not work. That is why I suggested that you should say which module provides the `uniq` function as it is not a built-in function. If you have code of your own that uses `uniq` then it must also `use` a module.